# Detecting if a plugin has been applied

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app that loads conversations. Each time a conversation is loaded I need to destroy and re init the file uploader.

Per: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API

I'm trying:

```
// First destroy existing instance
$('.upload').fileUpload('destroy');
    // Init
$('.upload').fileUploadUI({
      ........
```

Problem is on first run I get an error: "Uncaught No FileUpload with namespace "file_upload" assigned to this element"

Any ideas on how I can somehow detect if the plugin has been applied and only then destroy? Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to detect if the plugin has been applied to an element using the "namespace" (as the plugin refers to it), which is the `.data()` key the plugin uses.

With the current [`defaultNamespace`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/d504651a344a00cd92aea10bdf26875305fa4eb3/jquery.fileupload.js#L18) being `'file_upload'`, try:

```
var upload = $('.upload');

if (upload.data('file_upload'))
    upload.fileUpload('destroy');
```

Instead of just:

```
$('.upload').fileUpload('destroy');
```

This will mirror the plugin's own test, which you can see around [line 920](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/d504651a344a00cd92aea10bdf26875305fa4eb3/jquery.fileupload.js#L920) of the current source.